# How to hide the page x of y when my jasper report has only one page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasper-reports 4.5.0 and i am generating the reports.My requirement is if my report has only one page then it should not display the page 1 0f 1.How can i do this.To display the page x of y I am using the below lines of code.

```
  <textField>
                <reportElement x="395" y="121" width="20" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="350" y="121" width="45" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PAGE"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="415" y="121" width="25" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["OF"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="440" y="121" width="19" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

This is the newly modified code.

```
<variable name="NPAGES" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Highest">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>

<textField>
                <reportElement x="395" y="121" width="20" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? $V{PAGE_NUMBER} : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="350" y="121" width="45" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? "PAGE" : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="415" y="121" width="25" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? "OF" : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="440" y="121" width="19" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? $V{NPAGES} : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a variable NPAGES which is set to the total number of pages in the report:

```
<variable name="NPAGES" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Highest">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Now, use that variable as a conditional to determine whether to display the Page Number:

```
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="395" y="121" width="20" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? $V{PAGE_NUMBER} : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="350" y="121" width="45" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? "PAGE" : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="415" y="121" width="25" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? "OF" : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="440" y="121" width="19" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{NPAGES} > 1) ? $V{NPAGES} : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

I tried this in one of my reports and it worked.

Comment: Hi,Thanks For giving the reply.This solution is working fine.But if my report has total 10 pages for the first two pages it is not showing the PAGE 1 OF 10,PAGE 2 OF 10 instead it is showing 10,10.From the third page onwards it is displaying fine as PAGE 3 OF 10.What might be the problem.

Comment: I made a change to my answer so that the last element is using the new NPAGES variable instead of PAGE_NUMBER evaluated at "Report" time. This should fix your problem. Note that if you consider this to be the right answer, you should check the little check mark next to the answer to let others know. Also, you can upvote the answer by clicking the little ^ next to the answer. This is standard stackoverflow protocol, and people will take your questions more seriously if you have a good rate of accepting answers. Thanks!

Comment: sorry,it doesnt work for me.The logic is something wrong.Now its displaying nothing on the first two pages and from the third page onwards PAGE 3 OF 2,PAGE 4 OF 3,PAGE 5 OF 4 like this.The total pages of my report are 10.

Comment: That actually doesn't even seem possible, could you copy and paste your new code onto the bottom of your original question please.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no direct way to achieve this. At the moment the engine is filling page 1, it doesn't know if there is going to be a page 2. Delayed evaluation times are not sufficient to work around this.

The simplest similar solution is to just hide "Page x of y" on page 1. This does not meet your stated requirement... but some folks like it well enough.

The best relatively simple solution is with a subreport. Create a main report which just executes your current report query. Create a boolean parameter called `$P{subreport_has_more_than_one_page}` (or, er, use a more succinct name). Hopefully you can use simple logic like knowing that your report will be multiple pages if it returns more than 25 rows. This is not necessarily possible... but in a very big percentage of real world cases it is indeed possible. If your pages depend on unpredictable wrapping long text, this might be tough.

Assuming you can determine the value for `$P{subreport_has_more_than_one_page}`, then you pass this parameter to a subreport. The subreport is simply your existing report. Armed with this value it's trivial to add a Print When Expression to 'Page x of y' on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this follow below steps.

step 1:create variable so that it will store the current page number.

```
<variable name="V_CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+1]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

step2:add text field,evaluationTime should be **Auto**.

Value will be

**$V{PAGE_NUMBER}>1?msg("Page {0} of {1}",$V{V_CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER},$V{PAGE_NUMBER}):" "**

so that PAGE_NUMBER value if is greater than 1 then print page *current_page* of *total_report_page* else **empty**.

ex:  page 1 of 3

```
<textField evaluationTime="Auto">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="475" y="37" width="74" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}>1?
```

msg("Page {0} of {1}", $V{V_CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER}, $V{PAGE_NUMBER}):" "]]>

Answer (score 0):

Use variable of `$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}` and `$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}` instead of page number. I tried make text field to display the page number. Then add this expression in the text field

```
$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES} > 1 ? "(PAGE/OF) "+$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+"/"+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES} : ""
```

Change the `evaluation time` to `master`.

This is the complete snippet of my text field.

```
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight" evaluationTime="Master">
    <reportElement x="315" y="108" width="179" height="20" uuid="0ea93412-058f-49a0-95ac-06728421e4f1"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="ThaiFontFamily" size="10"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES} > 1 ? "(PAGE/OF) "+$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+"/"+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES} : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

NOTE: I think this only works if you have one master report and not using subreport.