# How to display the page x of y for only the reports which are having more than one page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using the jasper reports-4.5.0. I am generating the reports in different formats using this jasper. I want to display the page X of Y in my reports. So I am using iReport provided page number text field which is available in palette. It is displaying the page number in all the reports even the reports which are having the single page also.

So my requirement is I don't want the page x of y if my report has only one page. How do I accomplish this?

The below code is presently i am using according to the given answer.

```
<textField>
                    <reportElement x="395" y="121" width="20" height="20">
                       <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_COUNT} > 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="350" y="121" width="45" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_COUNT} > 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
```

If i used like this i am not getting the page numbers in the reports which are having the more than one page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide the page x of y when my jasper report has only one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928415/how-to-hide-the-page-x-of-y-when-my-jasper-report-has-only-one-page)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Print When Expression` for the two fields that contain `"Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"` and `" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}`. The jrxml portion with this two fields should look something like:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement uuid="90a3462d-cfa2-4768-904a-1edf4191f1b7" x="250" y="16" width="80" height="20">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_COUNT} > 1]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement uuid="01d43267-3247-48bb-9822-8b58ea860d7f" x="330" y="16" width="40" height="20">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_COUNT} > 1]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Hi jschoen,Thanks for giving the reply.If i used the code you mentioned i am not getting the page numbers in reports which are having the more than one page.For your easy understanding i am posting the code also what ever i am using in my original question.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @user1434746 Can you also edit the question to include the variable definition from the jrxml? My guess is that is where the problem is.

Comment: Hi,I did not define any variable for this page numbers.IS it required to define any variable.

Comment: I think the Print When will necessarily evaluate "Now" despite the textField evaluating at "Auto" or "Report". So depending on the logic he'll always get the field or never; but it won't display the field only when the total number of pages is greater than one. (I have not tested to confirm.)

Comment: the PAGE_COUNT variable is the number of records on the current page, not the total number of pages.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann You are correct. I'll try to fix this up tonight when I get home to make it correct also. It looks like you just use the PAGE_NUMBER and set the evaluation time to report for the textFieldExpression. Don't have iReprot infront of me at the moment to check that though.