# JasperReports: How to set visibility condition for fields with 'Page X of Y' expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I am generating the reports using *JasperReports*. 
I'm using two fields contains `Page X of Y` expression. Is it possible to hide this fields in case the report contains only one page?

Comment: I dont want to show the page x of y if my report has only one page.If the report has more than one page then it has to show page x of y.I think it is cleared now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the page x of y for only the reports which are having more than one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242490/how-to-display-the-page-x-of-y-for-only-the-reports-which-are-having-more-than-o) & [How to hide the page x of y when my jasper report has only one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928415/how-to-hide-the-page-x-of-y-when-my-jasper-report-has-only-one-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field property "Print When Expression" with a expression like that:

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} > 1
```

But you have to set this as well: evaluationTime="Report"

Comment: Hi,Vyccus Thanks for giving the reply.Can you explain it some what briefly.I am not getting what you are saying.I am new to jasperreports.

Comment: Yes, sure. I'm assuming that you already have those fields (x of y) right? Them you have to select them and open the properties tab, there  you'll find a property called "Print When Expression", this is used to print something, in your case fields, when some boolean expression is true. So, since you only want to print your fields when you amount of pages is more than 1, you can use a variable that already exists on your jasperreport (that's the $V{PAGE_NUMBER}). To  make it work correctly displaying the total, you also have to set eh evaluationTime with the value "Report"

Comment: btw, this property is in the same property tab that the "Print When Expression" is. Take a look at this and tell me if it works.