# Print line when first page is also last page

Tags: jasper-reports

How to print a line in JasperReports's report when there is only one page is present (first page and last page is same)?

Line is in background. if there is only one page then Tittle & Lastpagefooter displays in that page. so how to give a condition in Line --> properties --> Appearance --> print when Expression (FirstPage == LastPage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the page x of y when my jasper report has only one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928415/how-to-hide-the-page-x-of-y-when-my-jasper-report-has-only-one-page) & [Compare current page number with last page number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298)

Comment: How to print a line?.... I can't understand you just like a line in the whole report?, how is number of pages related?

Comment: @Petter I'm guessing, that it can be some type of "footer" (something like footer in a document generated via MS Word) or something like a drawing of symbol "Z" on a official documents to occupy all free space of document

Comment: @Petter Friberg and @ Alex K , Line is in background. if there is only one page then Tittle & Lastpagefooter displays in that page. so how to give a condition in Line --> properties --> Appearance --> print when Expression (FirstPage == LastPage)

Comment: @RijomonThomas please [edit] your question with this information, have you checked the duplicates pass by Alex, consider also these, if different explain in question, we need as much info as possibile in question